# Livewire is not being found

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel app in which I'm using Livewire to create components. I've declared Livewire in my app.blade.php file (template for ALL pages), like this:

```
    @livewireScripts
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/createCharts.js') }}"></script>
    @stack('scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}" defer></script>        
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

The thing is, this is working fine in all pages except one. I have a page 'funcionario' which accepts a parameter on the URL, as seen:

```
Route::get('/funcionario/{id}', [FuncionarioController::class, 'show'])->name('funcionario.show');
```

The error I'm getting is this:

[image]

What I think is weird, is that the URL to the Livewire script contains 2 times '/public'... I have no idea what is happening.

Comment: There should in fact be _no_ `/public` folder in your URLs. You should either have a vhost with `public` being the "DocumentRoot" or run `php artisan serve` from your project folder

Comment: But i'm not the one who 'created' the URL, as seen in my question, i'm calling the script as '@livewireScripts', as said in the Livewire documentation.. And i didn't changed the scripts folder, i followed the Livewire documentation to create it...

Comment: Which url is used on pages where Livewire works?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/rh-disemp/public/vendor/livewire/livewire.js?id=90730a3b0e7144480175
The only diference is that where Livewire works, there is only 1 '/public'... That's what's wierd about it.. I can't find an explanation for this

Comment: And your "base url" for that project is `localhost:8080/rh-disemp/public`? If so, you might want to re-read my first comment

Comment: No, my base URL defined in the .env file is: APP_URL=http://localhost:8000.. as i said, the '/public' is being created automatically using the Livewire directives

Comment: If anybody faces the same problem as i did, what worked for me was: change the 'asset_url' in the 'livewire.php' file inside the config folder to ''asset_url' => env('APP_URL'),'